# Sammy.js form cleared when back button pressed

Tags: jquery, back-button, sammy.js

I'm new to using sammy.js.
I want to post a form and get the results via ajax. I'm using sammy.js because when a user clicks on a result they will be redirected to a new page and when they want to return to the form page again the form will be wiped out if I'm not using something like sammy.js.

The problem is that it's not working. If i go back by the "back button" the form will be cleared out anyways.

this is my code:

```
var app = $.sammy(function()
{
 this.get("#/", function()
 {
 });

 this.post("#/filter", function()
 {
  fields = this.params;
  this.app.swap();
  $("#get_result").html(fields);
 });
});

$(function()
{
 app.run("#/");
});
```

This is my form:

```
<form action="#/filter" method="post" id="searchForm">
<input type="text" name="test"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your post route `#/filter` doesn't actually cause a hashchange in the browser's address bar, instead it performs a silent submit to the `#/filter` route. So when you hit the back button, it goes back to your previous route before the initiated `#/` route, whatever that may be. It also wouldn't make sense to redirect them back to the post route because we don't want the user to double post the form.

What you could do is keep an in memory variable and refer back to it every time you go back to the main route. For example:

```
var app = $.sammy(function()
{
 var lastSearch = '';
 this.get("#/", function()
 {
   $('#searchForm input:first').val(lastSearch);
 });

 this.post("#/filter", function()
 {
  lastSearch = $('#searchForm input:first').val();
  fields = this.params;
  this.app.swap();
  $("#get_result").html(fields);
 });
});

$(function()
{
 app.run("#/");
});
```